# Flutter on windows debug issue with gradle

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, flutter

I am getting an error when I try to debug my flutter app, I am running windows 10 on a surface pro. I copied the project from my other windows 10 machine which debugging worked correctly on so I am thinking this may be the issue. I am completely new to flutter.

ERROR

"* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\FlutterDev\lbconnect\lbconnect\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\FlutterDev\lbconnect\lbconnect\android\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  >   The SDK directory 'C:\Users\Sam.Cromer.2017011SC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)"

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. When you copy a flutter project and run it on a different machine you need to update the sdk.dir value in local.properties :)